# How to log in to salesforce community from external website

Tags: single-sign-on

I have a scenario as below. Users login to an application( external non salesforce) after using their credentials. After they login, they have a button which redirects them to salesforce community. The community is public now. So whoever has the URL, can view the community. The requirement is to make the community private and allow only authorized(app logged in users,external identity provider) users to view the community. I am not sure how to achieve this. After researching I found that openid connect is the solution. But I am not sure how to use it. The online material shows how to do it using google, facebook etc. Is there any documentation, I can refer to, that has the steps to do it?

Comment: if you need to look for documentation, i would suggest you use https://help.salesforce.com/ i searched for openid connect and there is plenty of doc returned in the query results

Comment: Hello glls. Thanks for the reply. I tried those and found lot of them. But none of them seems to match my requirement. It talks about logging to external app using salesforce and creating buttons in salesforce community. Not the other way round

Comment: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sso_tips.htm&language=en_US&type=0

Comment: Again it talks about openid. But there are no steps on how to configure it. At least if they had provided the steps, it would have helped people to learn

Answer (score 3, accepted):

searching the H&T portal can be helpful when looking for Salesforce related documentation.

Is there any documentation, I can refer to, that has the steps to do it?

Here it is:

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sso_provider_openid_connect.htm&type=0&language=en_US&release=208.12

fyi: there is also an [Implementation Guide](https://resources.docs.salesforce.com/208/latest/en-us/sfdc/pdf/salesforce_single_sign_on.pdf)

Comment: thnx bro. I will give it a try and hopefully I can resolve my issue

Comment: feel free to post any specific questions if you are stuck at a step

Comment: I appreciate your support @glls.